# Как пишется "кока-кола"?

Tags: орфография

Я часто встречаю написание кока-колы с маленькой буквы и без кавычек. Это правильно? (о качестве этой отравы говорить не будем))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое написание (со строчной и без кавычек) зафиксировано в словарях, следовательно, это норма (см., например Орфографический словарь под ред. Лопатина, сайт www.slovari.ru и др.). Превращение имени собственного в имя нарицательное свидетельствует о том, что называемый этим именем продукт пошел в массовое производство. Где уж тут о качестве говорить :-))))